# Make several POST CURL API in one request PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, request

I am trying to do some POST with CURL in some way, I explain:

I am using the `PhpExcel` library, the idea is to upload an excel file that contains a table with several records and the names of the field, with a `PhpExcel` function I go through each record, so I save it in an array.

The next step is to make a request that sends each of the records to a URL, in this case it is an API URL to edit several products, waiting for parameters (which are each of the fields that are sent in a record) , I have already armed the function to send a single request, I just need to know how I can send several records at once in a single request.

**Summary:**

1. I upload the excel file that contains several records. (done)
2. I keep these records in an array through a function that collects the contents of PhpExcel (done)
3. Make a POST request with CURL that runs through each of the records and send them at the same time (I have only managed to send only one record)

This code is for call function send POST

```
private function peticion_get_post($ruta,$formdata,$tipo){
    $apiurl = 'https://url/api/v1/';
    $url = $apiurl.$ruta;
    $postvars = '';
    foreach($formdata as $key=>$value) {
        $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    if($tipo == 'GET'){
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url."?".$postvars);
    }
    if($tipo == 'POST'){
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $tipo);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $tipo);//0 for a GET request y 1 para POST
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
    $resultado = json_decode($respuesta);
    return $resultado;
}
```

This code is for call function before and sends content from form

```
$formdata_post = array(
    'id_box' => $id_box,
    'number' => $number,
    'label' => $label
);
$ruta = 'edit.json';
$resultado_post = $this->peticion_get_post($ruta, $formdata_post, 'POST');
```

I work with Codeigniter, currently, I send the content by `JSON` through a form and just send a record, I just have to edit the form and send the content that is in the array that generated the `PhpExcel` when uploading the file.

Comment: Can you please provide code examples with what you have already tried?

Comment: Yes, I just did it, you can see the code in the post.